# Convert a string of a list to a list Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

Little stuck here, let's say I have a variable, we'll call it a, equal to:

```
var a = "['Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example3']"
```

How can I convert a to list, so it can be accessed with `a[2]` (for example)

```
//Make it so a is converted to a list, seeing as though it is a list, besides the two " on either side
var a = "['Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example3']"
var b = ['Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example3'] //<-- How can I get this?
```

What I've tried:

```
var a = "['Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example3']"
var b:Array = a // This did not work, hence this question.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they really single quotes, or double ? Because it could have been JSON (and easily converted).

Comment: Is this the real life? Is this just fantasy?

Comment: Suggestion: remove leading `['`, remove trailing `']`, then split by `', '`. Will break horribly if syntax is not respected.

Comment: What is the source of this string in the first place? It's a terrible data format

Comment: Can your strings in the quotes contain apostrophes, and if so, are you going to be escaping those? (And as everyone else has pointed out, your life would be much easier if you stick with a standard format like JSON, or even XML. Just share information about where this string is coming from and we can advise you further.)

Comment: If you really need this `let b = a.substring(with: a.index(a.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)..<a.index(a.endIndex, offsetBy: -3)).components(separatedBy: "', '")`

Answer (score 2):

You have a string that is not in any valid data serialization format I am aware of. (It's not quite JSON, for example.)

There is no straightforward way to convert that string to a "list" (array?)

You would have to write a bunch of string parsing code to do so.

If you used double quotes rather than single quotes it would be valid JSON and you could use the JSONSerialization class to convert it to an array.

If you used `replaceOccurrencesOfString: "'", withString: "\""` to convert the single-quotes to double quotes then you could convert the resulting string to Data, and from there to an Array object.

### EDIT:

The code to do everything beginning to end looks like this in Swift 3:

```
var string = "['Example 1','Example 2','Example3']"

//Replace ` characters with "
string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "\"")

//Try to convert the string to Data using utf8 encoding
guard let data = string.data(using: .utf8) else {
  fatalError()
}

let array = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

print("array = \(array)")
```

Note that I was lazy above. If the data conversion fails, I throw a fatal error, and I use the `try!` form of try, which will crash if the JSON conversion fails. In real code you'd want error recovery on both of those.

### EDIT #2:

After adding a try block around the JSON call, converting the whole thing to a function, trying to cast the results to an array of strings, and joining the resulting array using linefeeds, we get the following:

```
var string = "['Example 1','Example 2','Example3']"

func convertFunkyStringToStringArray(_ string: String) -> [String]? {
  
  let adjustedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "\"")
  guard let data = adjustedString.data(using: .utf8) else {
    return nil
  }
  do {
    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    return result as? [String]
  } catch  {
    print("Error \(error) deserializing string as JSON")
    return nil
  }
}

if let array = convertFunkyStringToStringArray(string) {
  let joinedString = array.joined(separator: "\n")
  print("After conversion, array = \(array). Joined, result = \n\(joinedString)")
} else {
  print("Unable to convert string to a [String] array")
}
```

As discussed, you'd be much better off making your original string use a conventional serialization format like JSON. (It is *almost* JSON. If you just used double quotes rather than single quotes, it would be valid JSON.)

Comment: This is a non-answer, but it's really the best you can get with this question.

Comment: How do I convert to data? `var b:Data = a.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "\"")` gives me an error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'Data'`

Comment: Two separate steps. Use the String function replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString to convert single-quotes to double quotes, and then use the String function `data(using:)` to convert the string to `Data`.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to Swift, using: what?

Comment: I'd suggest  NSUTF8Encoding.

Comment: That works, but how do I then convert it to an array? It prints as bytes, and I tried `var d:Array = c` With c being `var c = a.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)`

Comment: JsonObject returns Any. He probably wants to cast it to [String]

Comment: Any idea why I can't `"\n".join(array)`

Comment: You can. You'll need to cast the result from type `Any` to `[String]` first, and then you can join it back together.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm very new to Swift and app development, and I really appreciate your help

Comment: See the final edit to my answer. I refactored into a function and added the try/catch block and casting to the correct array type, as well as a sample join to combine the parts into a string with line feeds like you asked for in your comments.